# How to right-align text in a SWT Table cell?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a SWT table which wrapped by the JFace TableViewer, but this problem also applies to org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.

When I use a StyledCellLabelProvider, the text is always left aligned, even when I use

```
colA.getColumn().setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
```

Here is the label provider and setup:

```
TableViewerColumn colA = new TableViewerColumn(measureTable, SWT.NONE);
colA.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        ModelItem item = (ModelItem) cell.getElement();
        cell.setFont(FONT_REGISTRY.get(MY_SPECIAL_FONT));
        cell.setText(item.getText());
        super.update(cell);
    }
});
```

Any sort of workaround would be great. For e.g, nesting a widget inside the table and right aligning the text in the widget somehow.

Platform: Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found a bug in `StyledCellLabelProvider`. It will not occur with any other `CellLabelProvider`.

`StyledCellLabelProvider` uses "owner draw" for drawing the `Table` cells. That means, the cell content is not drawn natively by the OS. It is drawn in an `SWT.PaintItem` event by the Table "owner".

`StyledCellLabelProvider` does not respect the alignment of the `TableColumn`. You can see the source [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#9oBwOhrJiYY/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/StyledCellLabelProvider.java&q=StyledCellLabelProvider&type=cs), the method `getTextLayoutForInfo(.)` is of interest.

A workaround could be to copy that class, fix the bug by adding

```
TableColumn col = ((Table)viewer.getControl()).getColumn(cell.getColumnIndex());
layout.setAlignment(col.getAlignment());
```

in the method `getTextLayoutForInfo(.)` (I didn't test this fix, but if it doesn't work, you should get the idea, and be able to make it work)

You should also add a bug report: [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org)

Comment: I am not sure why I was even using StyledCellLabelProvider, I just changed it to use CellLabelProvider and the alignment worked... Thanks a lot.